# What glue to use for edge bonds on a laptop NB

Tags: reflow, bga

I'm trying to reball the northbrige of my HP Pavilion DV4-1212LA because it stopped working from one day to the other. I've checked, and all of the voltages are present. The laptop itself posts the error code of a malfuntioning VGA (failed to initialize). I was able to get it to partially work by reflowing, but there are some artefacts on the bottom end of the screen (coloured lines), culprit of bad contact.

Since for reflowing to have any effect on the board, I had to remove the four glue blobs that are on the corners of the chip, so when the solder got hot, it would lower and hopefully make better contact. The thing is that I want to reball this chip once and never have to deal with it again. Pavilions are known for this kind of issues. The problem is on the cooler solution of the NB (2mm thermal pad), and it can be solved by adding a solid copper "thermal pad" between the NB and the cooling solution

From what I've read [here](https://www.ansys.com/blog/bga-and-qfn-failure-mitigation-underfilling-edge-bonds-and-corner-staking-physics-of-failure), those glue blobs are actually there to prevent chips from having phisical damage due to strain on heat cycles and phisical stress, so ideally I would like to replace them after succesfully reballing the chip. The thing is that there are a lot of different glues intended for staking, and I dont really know where to start from.
Do any of you have any recommended glue to use for this kind of applications?

Ideally it would be nice to use the same glue that was used from the factory, but HP didn't print numbers on them, so I'm lost :/

Comment: You want a structural adhesive of some sort.  Most are two-part products.

Comment: *I was able to get it to partially work by reflowing* So, you had a thermocouple right on the PCB under the chip, and have measured a temperature high enough for solder to actually reflow? Most people heat things up to 150C or so and call it "reflowing" even though it's nothing of the sort. Unless you can measure things, you won't know what's happening.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I dont have a thermocouple, but this is what I did: Add a generous amount of flux to three sides of the NB, Preheat board to 115cº for an hour, Add more flux to the same three sides, Focus the heatgun to the NB at 350cº for two minutes, put PCB back in the oven (off) so it cools down gradually, and clean. Maybe the reflow was done correctly, but given the fact that I dont have an ultrasonic cleaner to remove all flux, maybe thats the issue. In any case, I want to check that all balls are making good contact, and I think reball is the best way to do so

Comment: While probably not something that's worthwhile for one-off use, they do make special heat gun adapters that fit over and down the sides of a BGA package to help getting heat to the balls.  This is one of the reasons you see some open space around the sides of a BGA package, at least on a well engineered design.

Comment: Have you considered using Pb/Sn solder instead of Pb-free solder for the reballing?

Comment: @SteveSh, this is not the case sadly. The NB is surrounded by more than 10cm of pcb on each side, and the closest edge is obstructed by an HDMI connector. The only way would be to preheat and then focus the heat

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, my idea is to replace the lead free solder for a leaded one. I've read that it has fewer "internal flaws" after cooling